# .Net Entity Framework Core: Constant value as foreign key in relation

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-core

I wanna configure relationship with constant value as foreign key in Entity Framework Core 7.0.4.

## Problem example:

Database models:

| PersonDailyReport |
| --- |
| string Name (PK) |
| string CityName (PK) |
| DateTime Date (PK) |
| bool IsCorrection (PK) |
| ... |

| DailyReport |
| --- |
| string CityName (PK) |
| DateTime Date (PK) |
| ICollection OriginalReports |
| ICollection CorrectedReports |
| ... |

Not database models:

| PersonData |
| --- |
| string Name |
| string CityName |
| ICollection Reports |
| ... |

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<PersonDailyReport>().HasKey(pdr => new { pdr.Name, pdr.CityName, pdr.Date, pdr.IsCorrection });
    modelBuilder.Entity<DailyReport>().HasKey(dr => new { dr.CityName, pdd.Date });

    modelBuilder.Entity<DailyReport>()
        HasMany(pd => pd.OriginalReports)
        .WithOne()
        .HasForeignKey(pdd => new { pdr.Name, pdr.CityName, pdr.Date, pdr.IsCorrection })
        .HasPrincipalKey(pd => new { dr.Name, dr.CityName, dr.Date, false }); // can't do this
    
    const bool false_ = false;
    modelBuilder.Entity<DailyReport>()
        HasMany(pd => pd.OriginalReports)
        .WithOne()
        .HasForeignKey(pdd => new { pdr.Name, pdr.CityName, pdr.Date, pdr.IsCorrection })
        .HasPrincipalKey(pd => new { dr.Name, dr.CityName, dr.Date, false_ }); // nice try: throws exception
}
```

I tried with "Discriminators" examples from here:
[How to configure relationship with a constant in the composite key for Entity Framework Core?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58814966/how-to-configure-relationship-with-a-constant-in-the-composite-key-for-entity-fr)

But without effect. I don't want to "discriminate" reports from `PersonData` from example.

Comment: Maybe is it possible to configure 'DailyReport' to get collection of 'PersonDailyReport' where 'IsCorrection' is "false" in another way?