# EF 6 foreign key relationship for not compliant naming convention database

Tags: c#, postgresql, entity-framework-core, linq-to-entities

I have two tables: `Products` and `Files`.

[image]

The `Products` table contains a FK column `photo_id` that references the `Files` table.
The `Products` table can also reference many files (pdf documents), with `entity_id` and `entity_type` columns.

Expected result: I am trying to get a list of `Products` with their respective photo.

`Product` class:

```
[Table("products")]
public partial class Product : Base
{
    [Key]
    [Column("id")]
    public int? Id { get; set; }

    [Column("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Column("photo_id")]
    public int? PhotoId { get; set; }

    public virtual File Photo { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<File> Files { get; set; }
}
```

`File` class:

```
[Table("files")]
public partial class File : Base
{
    [Key]
    [Column("id")]
    public int? Id { get; set; }

    [Column("filename")]
    public string Filename { get; set; }
}
```

`DbContext` class, `OnModelCreating` method:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(builder);
}
```

When querying...

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<Product>> Get()
{
    List<Product> rows;

    rows = await _context.Product
                         .Include(p => p.Photo)
                         .ToListAsync<Product>();
    return rows;
}
```

I am getting this error message:

> "ClassName": "Npgsql.PostgresException",
> "Message": "42703: column f.ProductId does not exist",
> "Data": {
> "Severity": "ERROR",
> "InvariantSeverity": "ERROR",
> "SqlState": "42703",
> "MessageText": "column f.ProductId does not exist",
> "Position": 987,
> "File": "parse_relation.c",
> "Line": "3643",
> "Routine": "errorMissingColumn"
> },

Why does EF expects my `File` table to have a `ProductId` column? How to avoid that?

I am using .NET 6, EF 6 and Postgres.

I have tried adding `ForeignKey` annotation like this:

```
[ForeignKey("photo_id")]
public virtual File Photo { get; set; }
```

...but it doesn't solve the problem. Any ideas?

**Update 1:**
After finding out the error message was about the Files collection property (thanks to @ivan-stoev), landed to this question [How to configure relationship with a constant in the composite key for Entity Framework Core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58814966/how-to-configure-relationship-with-a-constant-in-the-composite-key-for-entity-fr)
I added `ProductFile` class, to use as discriminator.

```
public class ProductFile : File
{

}
```

Then in `OnModelCreating`

```
base.OnModelCreating(builder);
        
        builder.Entity<File>()
            .HasDiscriminator(f => f.EntityType)
            .HasValue<ProductFile>("product");
```

but in this part, I get a syntax error:

```
            builder.Entity<Product>()
            .HasMany<ProductFile>()
            .WithOne()
            .HasForeignKey<Product>(p=> p.Id)
            .HasPrincipalKey<ProductFile>(pf=> pf.entity_id);
```

I am not sure how to follow.

Comment: You can add that (with uncommented `ForeignKey`) and add this on top statement `using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;`

Comment: EF 6 is EF **Core** 6, right? I cannot reproduce with just the included code in a clean project, can you? There must be something missing in the post. What is `Base`? Classes are `partial`, do they have additional definitions in another code file(s)? Is there  something like `public virtual ICollection<File> Files { get; set; }` ?

Comment: You are right @IvanStoev there is also a Files collection for pdf documents. I'm editing my question. How should i define this relationship?

Comment: Well, `Files` collection explains why EF expects `File` to have FK property/column `ProductId` - this is the only way relational database can represent such one-to-many relationship. What about `Photo`, it is *separate* relationship and will use `PhotoId` FK property (with corresponding column named "photo_id").

Comment: About the `Files` collection, I think I will need an additional `ProductFiles` class and define a discriminator. But I am getting syntax errors...
Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58814966/how-to-configure-relationship-with-a-constant-in-the-composite-key-for-entity-fr

Answer (score 0):

You have violated the default conventions for [discovering foreign keys & relationships](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships/foreign-and-principal-keys) by changing the name of property `PhotoId` to `photo_id`.

You have multiple ways to fix this:

- In the `OnModelCreating` method, you can explicitly tell EF Core that `photoId` is a FK for `Photo` property, like this:

  ```
  modelBuilder.Entity<Product>().HasOne(x => x.Photo).WithOne();
  ```
- You can remove `Column["photo_id"]` attribute, then EF Core can discover the relationship automatically.

You can read more about the conventions of relationship discovery in EF Core [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships) & [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships/conventions).

Comment: When modifying OnModelCreating, I get this message: "column f.ProductId does not exist".
When removing Column["photo_id"] I get message: "MessageText": "column p.PhotoId does not exist",
        "Hint": "Perhaps you meant to reference the column \"p.photo_id\"."

Comment: -have you added new migration after trying one of the solutions above? if not then add new migration , if yes, then try to add attribute [ForeignKey("Photo")] over the property  "PhotoId" and add new migration and see if the migration contains the code for foreign key, and look at this link for more help https://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/configuration/data-annotation-attributes/foreignkey-attribute#:~:text=The%20ForeignKey%20attribute%20is%20used%20to%20specify%20which,Entity%20Framework%20Core%27s%20convention%20for%20foreign%20key%20names.

Comment: I don't think they violated the FK naming conventions you are linking to, since they are based on **property** (not *column*) names. The way shown in the question, their model actually works, so the problem should be caused by something else. It's good to first test/reproduce the issue before trying to answer.