# EF Core 6 One-to-many relationship with discriminator

Tags: c#, postgresql, entity-framework-core

I am trying to define a one-to-many relationship (one Product may have many Files) with columns `entity_type` (discriminator) and `entity_id`  (in this example, entity_type indicates the row relates to a Product row and entity_id indicates the product id). Other possible values (entities) for `entity_type` are: PROD, USER, CONTACT, COMPANY.

[image]

I think this reference may help, but im not getting it work: [How to configure relationship with a constant in the composite key for Entity Framework Core?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58814966/how-to-configure-relationship-with-a-constant-in-the-composite-key-for-entity-fr)

I have the following classes:

`Product` class:

```
public class Product
{
    [Key]
    public int? Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ProductFile> Files { get; set; }
}
```

`ProductFile` class (for use as discriminator):

```
public class ProductFile : File
{
}
```

`File` class:

```
public class File
{
    [Key]
    public int? Id { get; set; }
    public string Filename { get; set; }
    public string EntityType { get; set; }     // discriminator
    public int? EntityId { get; set; }
}
```

But I am not sure how to define the relationship and I am getting syntax error in this method:
`DbContext` class, `OnModelCreating` method:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
{
     base.OnModelCreating(builder);
                      
     builder.Entity<File>()
          .HasDiscriminator(f => f.EntityType)
          .HasValue<ProductFile>("PROD");

     builder.Entity<Product>()
          .HasMany(e => e.Files)     
          .WithOne()
          .HasForeignKey(e=> e.Id)
          .HasPrincipalKey<ProductFile>(e=> e.EntityId);
}
```

I am using .NET 6, EF Core 6 and Postgres.

Any ideas?

Some other classes:

`User` class:

```
public class User
{
    [Key]
    public int? Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<File> Files { get; set; }
}
```

`Contact` class:

```
public class Contact
{
    [Key]
    public int? Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<File> Files { get; set; }
}
```

`Company` class:

```
public class Company
{
    [Key]
    public int? Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<File> Files { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you use entity `ProductFile` as discriminator where you should configure the discriminator on `OnModelCreating`.

Here is modified entity:

```
public class Product
{
    [Key]
    public int? Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<File> Files { get; set; } // Change to File, not ProductFile
}

public class File
{
    [Key]
    public int? Id { get; set; }
    public string Filename { get; set; }
    public string EntityType { get; set; } // discriminator
    public int? EntityId { get; set; }
}
```

Here is modified `DbContext` class, `OnModelCreating` method:
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
{
base.OnModelCreating(builder);

```
    builder.Entity<File>()
        .HasDiscriminator<string>("EntityType")
        .HasValue<File>("FILE")
        .HasValue<ProductFile>("PROD"); // Discriminator values for File and ProductFile

    builder.Entity<Product>()
        .HasMany(p => p.Files)
        .WithOne(f => f.Product)
        .HasForeignKey(f => f.EntityId);
}
```

Comment: You got the point, but I have some questions:
1. Maybe it is not necessary to have a `ProductFile` class?
2. `EntityType` possible values are PROD, USER, CONTACT, COMPANY (entities with the same relationship type). Maybe this line  `.HasValue<File>("FILE")` is not neccesary?
3. I am getting syntax error in this line `.WithOne(f => f.Product)`  am I missing some definition?

Comment: The decision to create a `ProductFile` class depends on whether you need to store specific properties or behavior related to files associated with products that are different from other entities like users, contacts, and companies. If files associated with products have unique attributes or functionality compared to files associated with other entities, then having a separate `ProductFile` class could make sense. However, if all files share the same attributes and behavior regardless of the associated entity, you can stick with just the `File` class.

Comment: The `.HasValue<File>("FILE")` line in your code is used to specify a default value for the EntityType discriminator column when the entity type is File. If all files should have the same EntityType value of `FILE`, you can keep this line. However, if you don't need this default value because it's not adding any meaningful information, you can remove it.

Comment: The syntax error in the line `.WithOne(f => f.Product)` is likely because there's no `Product` navigation property in your `File` class. To establish a relationship between `Product` and `File`, you should modify your `File` class like this:`public class File
{
...
public virtual Product Product { get; set; } // Navigation property to Product
...
}`

Comment: So in that case, in my `File` class, I should add a navigation property to `Product` ... and also to `User`, `Contact` and `Company`.

Comment: In above code, in `Product` class, there is List of `File` property. I am not sure about `User`, `Contact` and `Company`. Please include those classes in your question

Comment: these classes also have a List of `File` property (I added the classes)